# Conditional counting of rows in orgtable

Tags: org-table

I'm using org-tables in which I have a peculiar problem where I would like to count only category-1, which could be empty for few rows, and display it in column-1 as shown below in the example. All the entries are text only.

| item-count | category-1 | category-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item-a | sub-item-1 |
| 2 | item-b | sub-item-1 |
| 3 | item-c | sub-item-1 |
|  |  | sub-item-2 |
|  |  | sub-item-3 |
| 4 | item-d | sub-item-1 |
|  |  | sub-item-2 |
| 5 | item-e | sub-item-1 |

The table has more than 1000 entries, so it is tedious task to do it manually. Any help is appreciated.